# How to use mysqli_fetch_array to get just one result from a select query?

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli

```
$sqlresult = mysqli_query($dbconnection, "SELECT datetime, pagecontent, 
editedby FROM content ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1");
```

I'm doing a Web Dev course & it says I can get just one result from my select query by using mysqli_fetch_array but I'm not sure how. I've tried googling but I can't find any answers that I understand.

In the datebase I have content, datetime & editedby.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: printf ("%s , %s , %s\n",$row["datetime"],$row["pagecontent"], $row["editedby"]);

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a more simpler way of outputting your results.

```
$query = "SELECT datetime, pagecontent,editedby FROM content ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $datetime = $row['datetime'];
        $pagecontent = $row['pagecontent'];
        $editedby = $row['editedby'];

        echo $datetime . " " . $pagecontent  ." " . $editedby;
    }
```